# Why do I keep getting this error when merging two sorted linked lists in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am writing a function to merge two sorted linked lists and return the sorted list. I keep getting this error. SIGABRT - Abort (abnormal termination) signal

```
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T> LinkedList<T>::merge(const LinkedList<T>& other) const {

  
LinkedList<T> L = *this;
  LinkedList<T> R = other;

  LinkedList<T> merged;

  if (L.head_ == nullptr) {
    return R;
  } else if (R.head_ == nullptr) {
    return L;
  } 
  
  
  while(L.head_ && R.head_) {
    if (L.head_->data < R.head_->data) {
      merged.pushBack(L.head_->data);
      L.head_ = L.head_->next;
      ++merged.size_;
    } else {
      merged.pushBack(R.head_->data);
      R.head_ = R.head_->next;
      ++merged.size_;
    }
  }
  
  while (L.head_ || R.head_) {
  if (L.head_) {
    merged.pushBack(L.head_->data);
    L.head_ = L.head_->next;
    ++merged.size_;
  } else {
    merged.pushBack(R.head_->data);
    R.head_ = R.head_->next;
    ++merged.size_;
  }
  }

return merged;
  
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

This is the error I am getting

```
due to a fatal error condition:
  SIGABRT - Abort (abnormal termination) signal
```

This is the pushBack function I have for a doubly-linked list

```
// Push a copy of the new data item onto the back of the list.
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::pushBack(const T& newData) {

  // allocate a new node
  Node* newNode = new Node(newData);

  if (!head_) {
    // If empty, insert as the only item as both head and tail.
    // The Node already has next and prev set to nullptr by default.
    head_ = newNode;
    tail_ = newNode;
  }
  else {
    // Otherwise, add the new item as the tail.
    // (We could rewrite this without the temporary variable "oldTail",
    //  but perhaps this way is clearer.)
    Node* oldTail = tail_;
    oldTail->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = oldTail;
    tail_ = newNode;
  }

  // update size
  size_++;
}
```

Comment: Are you allocating memory with new? Have you defined a copy constructor and is it doing a deep  copy? Also `merged` looks like it goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: It could be that sometimes L.head_->next is null.

Comment: Erase the first `while` loop , it's seems to be useless, and use debugger to check if the case is the `nullptr` of the `L. head_->next` or `R. head_->next`.

Comment: Yes I have a copy constructor defined. I tried allocating memory with new but it gave me an error can you explain what you meant?

Comment: Thanks yes the first loop is useless. The nullptr is of the R.head->next. What should I edit? The function should work for different linked lists so why would I need to know if it's left or right in this case? @m-zayan

Comment: Try `else if(R.head_)`  instead of `else`.

Comment: It gave me the same error when I removed the first while loop. Shouldn't the loop exit before trying to dereference any null pointers or is there something I'm missing? @m-zayan

Comment: Could you add the error to the question?, It could be that  `L` or `R` empty (`.head_`) is `nullptr`

Comment: I added the error. I think the empty case is covered by the first if statements? I am passing the unit tests for the empty lists but the one causing my program to crash is where both lists are non empty. Sorry for the many questions @m-zayan

Comment: Please add your `pushBack` function, `.head_` is `nullptr` from the beginning, `while(L.head_ || R.head_)`.

Comment: But if it's nullptr from the beginning wouldn't the if statement catch it and return the function? Is there something I am missing? I added the pushBack function. @m-zayan

Comment: Have you defined a copy constructor? as Mr. **jackw11111** mentioned. 

`Node* newNode = new Node(newData);` if you are not defining a copy constructor then, the assignment operator (copy object) of `Node` class going to fail.

Comment: I didn't write the header file myself because it was provided but yes it has a copy constructor and I don't think there's a problem outside of my code because the header file was provided so it should be correct. The code included in my question is the only part I wrote so tI think here must be an error there. Sorry for bothering you but I've been stuck on this for a long time. @m-zayan

Comment: Check that you    `#include "linked_list_file.cpp"` not `. h` at `main.cpp`.